# Powerbi Power Query Editor Error converting string to number

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I import a data set from SQLite3 that contains some columns with numbers (stored as text in SQLite).  In Power Query I attempt to convert these strings to numbers using Transform->Table->Data Type: Decimal Number.  This however returns an entire column of `Error`

I have attempted to this manually by creating a Custom Column with `Number.FromText(string_value)`.  This produce the same result.
I have also tried to *clean* the data using Transform->Text Column->Format->Clean.

All the values are properly formatted as simple numbers eg:

`8.0`
`1.9`
...

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your default culture setting expects comma instead of dot. Set optional parameter to culture where the dot is used.

```
Number.FromText(string_value , "en-US")
```